# Why does my code make this weird shape instead of a circle?

Tags: python, image, trigonometry

I have an image. I make a large cirlce in that image.
I want to place 300 black dots evenly spaced out on the perimeter of the circle.
The dots don't form a cirlce instead the form some sort of star.
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlfMw.png)

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import math

Img = Image.open("C:\TMP\Lily1.jpg")
Img = Img.convert("L")
s = 700
Img = Img.resize((s, s), resample = Image.Resampling.BILINEAR)
Img = np.array(Img)

def Show(arr):
    Img = Image.fromarray(arr, "L")
    Img.show()

def Dis(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return ((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) ** 0.5

nNails = 300
x = 0
y = 0
sx = len(Img[0]) / 2
sy = len(Img) / 2
radius = s * 0.5 - 5
Canvas = np.array(Img, copy = True)

for a in range(int(sy * 2)):
    for b in range(int(sx * 2)):
        if Dis(sx, sy, b, a) < radius:
            Canvas[a, b] = 255

nailPos = []
for a in range(nNails): # Making the positions of the dots.
    radAngle = (360 / nNails) * a * (math.pi / 180)
    print(radAngle)
    xcor = math.cos(radAngle) * radius 
    ycor = math.sin(radAngle) * radius
    nailPos.append([xcor, ycor])

for a in nailPos:
    Canvas[round(a[1]), round(a[0])] = 0 # Coloring the dots black


Show(Canvas)
```

I've implemented this in desmos and their it work fine. It makes a circle and not a star.

Comment: Some of your coordinates are negative, which will cause unexpected behaviour when setting array elements in `Canvas`. You should be able to fix this by adding `sx` and `sy` (the coordinates of the centre of the canvas) when calculating each `xcor` and `ycor`.

Answer (score 2):

```py
xcor = math.cos(radAngle) * radius + round(sx)

ycor = math.sin(radAngle) * radius + round(sy)
```

Because 0, 0 in the array is not the same as 0, 0 in the circle.
So i add the half of the height and half of the length to the coordinates to center it.